# Why few partitions are processed twice if mapPartitions is used with toDF()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to process partition per partition (long story).

Using `mapPartitions` is working fine when using RDDs. In the example, when using  `rdd.mapPartitions(mapper).collect()` all work as expected.

But, **when transforming to DataFrame, one partition is processed twice**.

Why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Following, the output of the next simple example. We can read how the function is executed 3 times, when there are only two partitions. One of the partitions `[Row(id=1), Row(id=2)]` is processed two times.
It is courious that one of the executions is ignored, as we can see in the DataDrame resulted.

```sh
size: 2 > values: [Row(id=1), Row(id=2)]
size: 2 > values: [Row(id=1), Row(id=2)]
size: 2 > values: [Row(id=3), Row(id=4)]
                                                                                +---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+
> Mapper executions: 3
```

Simple example used:

```py
from typing import Iterator

from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def gen_random_row(id: str):
    return Row(id=id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[1]").appName("looking for the error").getOrCreate()
    executions_counter = spark.sparkContext.accumulator(0)

    rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
        gen_random_row(1),
        gen_random_row(2),
        gen_random_row(3),
        gen_random_row(4),
    ], 2)

    def mapper(iterator: Iterator[Row]) -> Iterator[Row]:
        executions_counter.add(1)
        lst = list(iterator)
        print(f"size: {len(lst)} > values: {lst}")
        for r in lst:
            yield r

    # rdd.mapPartitions(mapper).collect()
    rdd.mapPartitions(mapper).toDF().show()

    print(f"> Mapper executions: {executions_counter.value}")

    spark.stop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is passing the schema to `toDF`

Looks like Spark is processing one partition to infer the schema.

To solve it:

```
    schema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), True)])
    rdd.mapPartitions(mapper).toDF(schema).show()
```

With this code, every partition is processed one time.

Comment: nice sleuthing, i have used `mapPartitions()` extensively and was unaware of this